# JavaScript - Parsing JSON with carriage and new line spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am using the following JS code to parse a JSON string from a separate JS file:

```
// extract JSON from a module's JS
var jsonMatch = data.match( /\/\*JSON\[\*\/([\s\S]*?)\/\*\]JSON\*\// );
data = JSON.parse( jsonMatch ? jsonMatch[1] : data );
```

This is an example of the JS file I extract the JSON string from:

```
JsonString = /*JSON[*/{"entities":[{"type":"EntityPlayer","x":88,"y":138}]}/*]JSON*/;
```

This code works just fine, however if the JS file with the JSON string contains carriage returns and isn't on one complete line then I get a syntax error.

Example:

```
JsonString = /*JSON[*/{
     "entities":[{
         "type":"EntityPlayer",
         "x":88,
         "y":138}]
     }/*]JSON*/;
```

Returns the following error:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

Any idea how I could modify my parsing to work by either stripping out whitespace or to remove carriage returns and new line spaces?

Comment: You could be overthinking it. How are you fetching this file? How do you get it's contents?

Comment: I am not seeing that problem: http://jsfiddle.net/UrQ7Y/

Comment: I agree with above probably best to try and get rid of the carriage returns and white space rather than code around it. In php you could use some like json_encode to do this for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = JSON.parse( (jsonMatch ? jsonMatch[1] : data).replace(/\n/g,"") );
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer, however the following was actually an issue where I wasn't closing a `StreamReader` object in my C# code.

Answer (score -1):

Did not test it, but maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
var JsonString = JsonString.replace(new RegExp( "\\n", "g" ),"");
```

(from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/161-Ask-Ben-Javascript-Replace-And-Multiple-Lines-Line-Breaks.htm)

Comment: Whitespace is perfectly valid in a JSON string.

Comment: Okay, sorry I understood the question in a wrong way. Though it's more or less java string replacement.